# Resetting Filters using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, commandbutton

I have a short piece of code to reset the filters applied to the columns on my worksheet.

```
Sub ResetFilters()

If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
Cells.AutoFilter
End If

End Sub
```

When I click the command button to run the macro, it works but the 'Reset Filters' command button disappears and the rest that I have on the sheet all stack up in the top left hand corner of the worksheet. They all have 'Don't move or size with cells' set as their property but they still move...

#### Command Buttons - Before resetting filters

[image: Command Buttons - Before resetting filters]

#### Command Buttons - After resetting

[image: Command Buttons - After resetting]

When I enter Design Mode, the 'Reset Filters' button reappears in the correct place... I am very confused - does anyone have any advice they can offer?

EDIT (14/06 16:41) - I have discovered that if I sort the data into ascending or descending order, the buttons stay where they are when I reset the filters. They only move if I have filtered out some of the data.

EDIT (14/06 17:58) - I have included a screenshot of what I am working with so that my filtering needs are clearer! I work in a school and teachers will analyse their data with this tool. They can filter any of the columns to analyse results and progress of specific children based on their characteristics or assessment results. As they can filter or sort many columns, it can be hard to reset the data without missing a column. I would like to add a 'Reset' button to make this job easier. (I will now likely add these to the ribbon as I have just created a bespoke school tab for this tool so that will remove the issue of the moving buttons. However, if there is a better method of resetting the filters, I would love to learn it.)

[Screenshot of the data analysis tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQL1b.jpg)

Many thanks.

Comment: Are they Form buttons or ActiveX controls?

Comment: They are ActiveX controls

Comment: Try using Form ones. They behave better generally.

Comment: Really? Thanks - I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `ActiveSheet`. It is prone to multiple errors.
   Use `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")` instead (change Sheet1 to the actual Sheet name that you are using)
2. If you are willing to remove literally all filters (and not only over a specific range), this will do

```
Private Sub clearfilters()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells.AutoFilter
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, both of you. I have realised that I need to reapply the filters after I have removed them as I wish the filters to still be used after resetting them. Is there a better way that you might recommend to do this?

Comment: Also, I assume that I should always avoid ActiveSheet and that I should define something as the worksheet then?

Comment: @gbra I don't think I understand what you're exactly trying to achieve then. Maybe edit the original question with pictures of data and expected result. And yeah, you should avoid using ActiveSheet altogether. Defining a concrete sheet with a variable (for example ws) is much better coding practice.

Comment: I have edited my post and added a screenshot to clarify things. Thanks for the advice about defining the sheet. :)